# If I know that $E(Z) = 0$ and that $Var(Z) = 0$, how can I show that $Z=0$ almost surely?

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I know that $E(Z) = 0$ and that $Var(Z) = 0$, I am trying show that $Z=0$ almost surely. By definition, it seems that as long as I can show that:

$$
P(\omega : Z(\omega) = 0) = 1
$$

My approach was via integration to recover the probability inside, but I am stuck and it seems that this is a very trivial fact. Does anyone have any hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

If $P(Z\neq 0)>0$ then $P(|Z|>\frac1{n})>0$ for $n$ large enough.

Based on that you can prove that $\text{Var}Z=\mathbb E[(Z-\mathbb EZ)^2]=\mathbb E[Z^2]>0$.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I repaired, and have no doubts that you are satisfied now ;)

Comment: If variance = 0, doesn't it necessarily follow that all values are centered at the mean/expected value ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Not all, but almost all: $P(Z=\mathbb EZ)=1$. The OP is searching for a proof ot this.